# Django South Migration Error: Key is Not Present

Tags: python, database, django, migration, django-south

I added these fields to my model:

```
class WatchList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Thing(models.Model):
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey(WatchList)
```

Ran the schemamigration successfully:

```
 >>> $ python2.7 manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
 + Added model myapp.WatchList
 ? The field 'Thing.watchlist' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ? Please select a choice: 2
 ? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
 ? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
 >>> 0
 + Added field watchlist on myapp.Thing
 Created 0004_auto__add_watchlist__add_field_thing_watchlist.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate myapp
```

I haven't had a problem before trying to do this, but for some reason I received the following error:

```
 >>> $ python2.7 manage.py migrate myapp
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "myapp_thing" ADD CONSTRAINT "watchlist_id_refs_id_1b2eef756112b8e" FOREIGN KEY ("watchlist_id") REFERENCES "myapp_watchlist" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
The error was: insert or update on table "myapp_thing" violates foreign key constraint "watchlist_id_refs_id_1b2eef756112b8e"
DETAIL:  Key (watchlist_id)=(0) is not present in table "myapp_watchlist".
```

How can I successfully migrate the changes to the models? Thanks for any ideas that might help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you specified `0` as the default value in the migration. Delete the migration and run it again, this time specify an empty string as the default.

If you already have some data in the database you'll need to specify `null=True` and `blank=True` in the ForeignKey or it'll break.

Comment: Okay thanks for your idea. I did that, this time entering `''` as the default value. However, this time received a different error: `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column "none" does not exist`. Am I missing something? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Okay, please see my edit. If that doesn't work you should at least get more clues from the error message.

Comment: Ok well hmmm unfortunately that did not work either. The error only says: `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column "none" does not exist`. Any other ideas that might help? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Oh wait I didn't realize you meant `ForeignKey(WatchList, null=True, blank=True)`. Instead I put it in the `WatchList` model field itself, which resulted in the problem. Changing it as you suggested fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Still applicable with Django 1.10. Helped me troubleshooting the issue; I just removed the single row I had and got rid of the error.